# Limiting a JSON string response from an API to select attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, asmx, webmethod

Currently, I am using a `[WebMethod]` to call an API and get the response as a `JSON` string.

```
 public string GetFloodData()
 { ...
     WebRequest requestObj = WebRequest.Create(url);
     requestObj.Method = "GET";
     requestObj.ContentType = "application/json";

     responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)requestObj.GetResponse();
     using (Stream stream = responseObj.GetResponseStream())
     {
       StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
       strresult = sr.ReadToEnd();
       sr.Close();
     }
     return strresult;
...
}
```

When I call `GetFloodData()`, I get the following response in the browser:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{"ListEvents": 
[{"EventID":1,"EventName":"Debby2000","State":"PR","EventType":"Tropical or 
Extratropical","Days":5,"LSTStart":"\/Date(9666432000000000)\/",
"LSTEnd":"\/Dat e(967075200000-0000)\/"}, {...}....]}
```

At this point (before I parse it as a formal `JSON Object`), I just want to eliminate the stuff I don't want (`"Days"`,`"LSTStart"`, and `"LSTEnd"`) and keep what I want. How would I limit what attributes are returned in my response?

Comment: Deserialize, transform, reserialize.

Comment: I want to do that later, but want to know if I can limit the attributes in my request. If not, can you give an example of Deserialize, transform, reserialize?

Comment: If you deserialize it to a concrete model  then any fields which aren't part of the model will be dropped by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can de-serialise it with a class, and in that class, you can write only the variables you do want to keep. Although, keep the structure of the Json and the class as same. Variables can be missing, but the structure should be the same

Comment: OK, I have deserialized it using a class and pushed everything into an ArrayList. The arraylist looks fine in my debugger (it's producing the correct results). My WebMethod function returns a string so I then convert it to a string like this: `return string.Join(" ", flood_dataset);` but when I invoke it I get : `<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">System.Collections.ArrayList</string>` . Ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: If you want to send a string back from your webMethod, I would suggest you use Json.serialise method. Use the link :  -https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm